# Crash when trying to run WebGoat with a Java Agent

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, javaagents

I am currently learning how to boot a web application with a java agent for monitoring.

The Web Application I chose was [WebGoat](https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat), and running WebGoat with `java -jar webgoat-server-8.0.0.M17.jar` as stated in WebGoat's README works perfectly fine.

However, when I try to add my agent, I get the following mess of an error log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.12.RELEASE)

2018-06-06 22:36:08.528  INFO 3741 --- [           main] org.owasp.webgoat.StartWebGoat           : Starting StartWebGoat v8.0.0.M17 on MacBook-Pro.local with PID 3741 (/Users/andrewfan/Desktop/Lang Agent Dev Proj help info/webgoat-server-8.0.0.M17.jar started by andrewfan in /Users/andrewfan/Desktop/Lang Agent Dev Proj help info)
2018-06-06 22:36:08.531  INFO 3741 --- [           main] org.owasp.webgoat.StartWebGoat           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-06 22:36:08.844  INFO 3741 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1376c05c: startup date [Wed Jun 06 22:36:08 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-06 22:36:11.354  INFO 3741 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e12590a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-06-06 22:36:11.442  WARN 3741 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webgoat.user.directory' in value "${webgoat.user.directory}"
2018-06-06 22:36:11.455  INFO 3741 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-06 22:36:11.464 ERROR 3741 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webgoat.user.directory' in value "${webgoat.user.directory}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at
```

...

I cut the error messages short since the trace is a few pages long, but the main error seems to be `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webgoat.user.directory' in value "${webgoat.user.directory}"`

---

I am running my agent as follows:
`java -javaagent:/Users/path/to/jar/Spn-LangAgent-0.0.jar -jar webgoat-server-8.0.0.M17.jar --server.port=8080 --server.address=localhost`

My agent is as follows:

```
package com.spnlangagent.langagent;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException;

import com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationRecorder;

public class LangAgent {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("LangAgent: premain now running");
        setupInstrumentation(agentArgs, inst);
        startRuntime(agentArgs);
    }

    private static void setupInstrumentation(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("setupInstrumentation: now running with agentArgs: " + agentArgs);
    }

    private static void startRuntime(String agentArgs) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("startRuntime: now running with agentArgs: " + agentArgs);
    }
}
```

The original contents of the agent were commented out except for a few print statements, and yet even with this, WebGoat is crashing on startup.

I tried another agent with WebGoat and it worked fine, so the only thing I can think of is that something is wrong with either my agent, or the way it is being packaged.

I am using Maven, and my MANIFEST.MF is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.spnlangagent.langagent.LangAgent
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
```

After running `mvn package`, the MANIFEST packaged in the .jar is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.spnlangagent.langagent.LangAgent
Built-By: andrewfan
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_172
```

In my pom.xml, I am doing the following to reach the manifest:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction in regards to figuring out why WebGoat is crashing, or if someone could provide more insight into why what I am currently doing is wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Note: If the rest of my pom.xml is necessary for debugging, I will gladly provide it; it's just that the question is already very long as-is.

Comment: So what makes you think it has to do with Java agent? The error message has been explicitly mentioning that it couldn't find `webgoat.user.directory` placeholder definition.  Have you passed enough param / set up your app correctly?

Comment: @AdrianShum I tested the exact same command-line invocation with another Java Agent and WebGoat booted without a problem, so I am inclined to believe that the problem is unrelated to how I'm attaching the agent to WebGoat.

Comment: You get a +1 for teaching me that a thing called "WebGoat" exists.

Comment: @markspace I'll link it in my post for context. [EDIT: Done. Instructions on how to run the application are in the WebGoat README]

Comment: With the very same environment which you just failed to run with agent, could you just remove the agent parameters and run plain Webgoat only? I don't believe it works.  I suspect you need to pass `-Dwebgoat.user.directory=blablabla/`  in your command

Comment: @AdrianShum The problem is that when I run `java -jar webgoat-server-8.0.0.M17.jar --server.port=8080 --server.address=localhost` (i.e. removing the -javaagent portion), WebGoat starts properly and goes live on localhost:8080.

Comment: my guess is, webgoat is looking up a properties/yaml file for its placeholders.  And your agent JAR included filename with same name, and (which I am not really sure) agent JAR may be in top of classpath which shadowed that property file.  Show us what is in your agent JAR

Comment: quickly glanced the source code of WebGoat.  `weboat.user.directory` (and other properties) are defined in file `application.properties`.  Please check if your Agent JAR provided the same file

Comment: @AdrianShum My .jar contains the following: `application.properties` (empty), `com/.../*.class`, `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, `META-INF/maven/.../pom.properties, xml`, and the remains of my old front-end (unused) in `public`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172646/discussion-between-andrew-fan-and-adrian-shum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webgoat (and also in most Spring-based application) relies on properties file (in `properties` or `yaml` format usually) to perform placeholder lookup.

The symptom in your failure indicate that Spring failed to lookup properties for placeholder processing.

Given that placeholder lookup works well without presence of your agent JAR, and with information you mentioned in comment, the problem is caused by

- Your agent JAR provided application.properties (which has name collision with the properties file used by Webgoat for placeholder)
- Agent JAR will be part of classpath, and probably even appear earlier than the main JAR
- your empty `application.properties` "shadowed" the one in Webgoat main JAR.  Which means, when Webgoat starts, Spring picked up your empty `application.properties` for its placeholder processing, hence failed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was `mvn clean`

Earlier I had an `application.properties` that was automatically added as part of the Spring Boot Initializr. The very presence of this file in my agent .jar, even with nothing inside, seems to have been the reason why WebGoat freaked out. Now that it is no longer present, WebGoat is running normally via `java -javaagent:/Users/path/to/jar/Spn-LangAgent-0.0.jar -jar webgoat-server-8.0.0.M17.jar --server.port=8080 --server.address=localhost`

I'd like to thank Adrian Shum for mentioning `application.properties`, since I had removed it a while back. `mvn package` didn't actually rebuild the .jar when I ran it, so the jar I had been testing on was the one that still contained `application.properties`.